# Jenkins failure Java 12 OpenJDK - The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly

Tags: java, jenkins, java-12

Configuring Jenkins (2.121.3) to use [JDK 12](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk12/GPL/openjdk-12_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz) in the Global Tool Configuration->JDK installations... menu using "Download URL for binary archive" produces the following error when performing a build:

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tar file has a directory called jdk-12 inside it, so when Jenkins extracts it, the named jdk folder is not the direct parent of the bin directory.

`/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java12/jdk-12/bin`

should be

`/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java12/bin`

To fix this, extract the tar file, go into the jdk-12 folder, `tar czf openjdk-12_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz *`, upload it somewhere accessible to Jenkins and put the URL in the "Download URL for binary archive" field in the Global Tool Configuration->JDK installations... installer.

Answer (score 0):

As [Robert Bain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55540294/418057) states, it is because there is a sub folder in the JDK archive.

Using more recent versions of Jenkins (2.375.1 in this instance), you can specify this sub folder in the Jenkins setup in the "Subdirectory of extracted archive" option.  Eg:

[image]

Comment: IIRC this was added in a later version of Jenkins than the 2.121.3 specified. Can you confirm what version you're using?

Comment: @RobertBain Yes, it probably was.  We have Jenkins 2.375.1.