# How to install Jenkins with JDK 15 on windows

Tags: java, jenkins

I have windows 10 machine with java version 15. (JDK 15)

I have installed Java 15 and set the path in environment variables.

I need to install Jenkins. I downloaded and installed Jenkins for windows (jenkins.msi) from -
https://www.jenkins.io/download/thank-you-downloading-windows-installer-stable/

When I tried to access localhost:8080, it displayed error - This site can’t be reached.

When referred to [Jenkins documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/), it says that Java 12 is not supported. Does it also not support Java 15? If so, how can I install Jenkins on windows?

Answer (score 0):

From the Jenkins site [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/), it says versions older than Java 8 are not supported.

> Older versions of Java are not supported
> Java 9 and Java 10 are not supported
> Java 12 is not supported

However, there seem to be a workaround on using OpenJdk 12 with Jenkins 2.121.3 on [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55540287/jenkins-failure-java-12-openjdk-the-java-home-environment-variable-is-not-defi) which could be of help.

If the above options don't help, I suggest you download and install Java 8 [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html), then the Windows Jenkins installer from https://www.jenkins.io/download/

Answer (score 0):

As of now, looks to be we dont have JDK15 supported jenkins. Me to waiting..

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `--enable-future-java`:

`java -jar jenkins.war --enable-future-java  --httpPort=8080`

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins only supported  java 8 or 11.

you can install any of this and then it will work.